# scrape data from 1 page go to next page and so on, javascript used on website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried many different web scraping avenues and hoping to get some help here.  I have some Python code that gets me what I want from page 1 of my website.

```
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='preblockBody')
results
print(results.prettify())
job_elems = results.find_all('table', class_='pbListingTable')
for job_elem in job_elems:
    title_elem2 = job_elem.find_all('tr', class_='pbListingTable1')
for pbListingTable1 in job_elem.find_all('tr', {'class':'pbListingTable1'}):
    print(pbListingTable1.text)
    title_elem = job_elem.find_all('tr', class_='pbListingTable0')
for pbListingTable0 in job_elem.find_all('tr', {'class':'pbListingTable0'}):
    print(pbListingTable0.text)
```

Then I would like to go to the next page and do the same thing, looping through all pages until the end and combining everything. However, I've had some trouble as the next page action is in javascript like so:

`<a href="javascript:gotoNextPage(2)">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</a>`

After further inspecting the website, I see that the action is:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function sortPage(i) {
document.location = baseHref + "website" + i;
}
function gotoNextPage(i) {
document.location = baseHref + "website" + i;
}
```

I'm fairly new to all this so I'm pretty stuck. Any guidance is appreciated greatly. How can I get to the next page, loop through them all, and then combine?

Comment: You may need to look into Selenium to handle the JS.

Comment: it's will be great if you share the `url` and tell us your expected output.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the url needs credentials so I've figured out that part as well, but I won't be able to share. The webpages are set up like tables, from the code I've shared you can see I'm finding the rows from the table and pulling in all the info. I'd like to do that for all pages.

Comment: a click is a click... just click the link.   XPATH of "//a[contains(@href, 'gotoNextPage(2)')]" should work.

Comment: Use your browser development tools to watch the network traffic and observe the URL it sends you to when clicking next page. Emulate the request it makes when you press next page.

Comment: I'm very much a newbie so apologies, if a click is just a click how can I automate with a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox()


driver.get(url)

##your code goes here##

nxt=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'gotoNextPage(2)')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nxt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for everyone's suggestions, I've rewrote using Selenium and now I'm just hoping to get some help looping through all the pages and append to a single output. Here is my code:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_id('preblockBody')

job_elems = table.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'pbListingTable')]")
for value in job_elems:
    print(value.text)

nxt=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'gotoNextPage(2)')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nxt)
```

Comment: this looks about right, but not sure why you are not using nxt.click() instead of executing a script.  You could loop here by using a simple "for" loop and using index for gotoNextPage part... so for the "2", use the index of the for loop.  You could also use Seleniums "findElements" to return an array of elements that match an xpath that contains "gotoNextPage" and iterate through that.  WebDriverWaits will help if the DOM is updated via javascript.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm struggling to get something to work. How can I get started, can I add something like [i] to the end of 'gotoNextPage' and loop through ?

Comment: yes... use proper quoting.. I'd post an example but I don't know Python.  You could also grab the array of elements using findElements and just ++ the index for the array after each click and whatever actions you are running... (if javascript creates those buttons, though, it gets a little more complicated with WebDriverWaits and catching StaleElement exceptions to make sure you catch the full array)

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm a bit new to Python to execute well...I'll see what I can find